# How to add a vertical line in echarts4r chart

Tags: r, echarts4r

I would like to add a vertical lines as showed on the image. Do you have any hint how to do it?[image]

```
df <- data.frame(
        data = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L),
       value = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L))

df %>%   
  e_charts(data) %>% 
  e_area(value) %>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>% 
  e_toolbox_feature(feature = "dataZoom") %>% 
  e_toolbox_feature(feature = "dataView") %>% 
  e_legend(right = 0) %>% 
  e_format_y_axis(suffix = "%")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `e_mark_line` with an `xAxis` value and empty title like this:

```r
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

df %>%   
  e_charts(data) %>% 
  e_area(value) %>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>% 
  e_toolbox_feature(feature = "dataZoom") %>% 
  e_toolbox_feature(feature = "dataView") %>% 
  e_legend(right = 0) %>% 
  e_format_y_axis(suffix = "%") %>%
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = 2), title = "") %>%
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = 6), title = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>